# Font size inside Swiper Slide gets bigger only on Mobile device

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, swiper.js

I'm using React with Swiper to create a slider. Problem is out of nowhere font size gets bigger *only* on mobile device, its fine when using desktop Chrome mobile mode or shrinking down window to mobile size.

**1. How it looks on Desktop Chrome device toolbar (how it should look normally):**

[image]

**2. How it looks on real mobile device, iphone:**

Font size got bigger out of nowhere, there is no css code that changes font size to this:

[image]

**3. When I use Safari extension to open console on mobile:**

First image shows given font size is 16px.

Second image is Computed Style that shows somehow it turned to 25px. There is no other selector that affects this element if this dev tool didn't miss it

[image]
[image]

**Related information about the issue:**

For Swiper to be in shape that I want, I'm giving around `width: 220%` to `.swiper` class, when I set it to 100% looks like font size doesn't turn big somehow, but I need to make width this way to have intended UI with sliders.

```
.swiper {
  width: 220%;
  margin-left: -60%;
}
```

Why does giving `width: 220%` changes font size mobile devices, does anyone know anything about it ?

Comment: not sure about the issue.
you can try with media query to add font size on particular width of the screen size

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Even when I try to give font-size:16px!important it doesn't effect, somehow mobile browser overrides it due to some reason. As I've understand something with the swiper/slider's code causes this(on mobile) when I try to use width more than 100%. In the end I've found another way to have my intended UI when width is 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've run into this issue too. Somehow long text within Swiper triggers MobileSafari's text inflation algorithm to enlarge the text to, supposedly, make it more readable. You can disable the browser's inflation algorithm by adding the following (we added it to the Swiper container, and it seems to have done the trick for us):

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```